# What happens if Hezbollah targets the USS aircraft carrier in the Mediterranean?

Tags: armed-conflict, israel, gaza, lebanon, hezbollah

The USS Aircraft Carrier Gerald R. Ford has arrived in the Mediterranean in a clear message to Hezbollah or any other party looking to escalate the conflict or widen the war between Israel and Gaza armed militias.

However the northern Israeli front has been flaring up recently and it is unclear whether the two, Hezbollah and Israel, are headed towards a major conflict.

If that happens and the U.S. aircraft carrier proved to be a serious hurdle for Hezbollah, it's unimaginable what would happen if Hezbollah successfully targeted the carrier with destructive weapons and sent it down to the bottom of the sea.

How would the U.S. respond if it actually loses its aircraft carrier due to a Hezbollah attack — could it be an invasion of Lebanon by U.S. and allied troops?

Comment: Welcome to Politics SE! Unfortunately, hypothetical questions like this are off-topic here, as they would be based entirely on speculation and not on any facts or resources available to the public. Please take the [tour](https://politics.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help) to learn what kinds of questions are on topic here, and feel free to [edit](https://politics.stackexchange.com/posts/81696/edit) your question if you feel you can make it on-topic.

Comment: If it's "unimaginable what would happen," isn't that the same as saying that it is not possible to answer this question?

Comment: @CDJB No, by "unimaginable" here, I meant difficult to imagine, not the literal meaning of the word.

Comment: The carrier group is still very far away from any land based position. Even high tech russian missiles would have a hard time sinking a carrier. Any attack will obviously result in retaliation. A carrier group has enough firepower to destroy the military infrastructure of any of the countries directly involved in the conflict.